# Prove that $\lim_{x \to 3} \sqrt{x+1} = 2$

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

Prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 3} \sqrt{x+1} = 2$

Attempt:

$0 < |x - 3| < \delta \Rightarrow |\sqrt{x+1} - 2| < \epsilon$

Well $|\sqrt{x+1} - 2| = |(\sqrt{x+1} - 2) \cdot \displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{x+1} + 2}{\sqrt{x+1}+2}| = |\frac{x-3}{\sqrt{x+1} + 2}| = |x-3| \cdot \frac{1}{|\sqrt{x+1}+2|}$

Here, the second term is the nuisance so maybe do something like the following:

Suppose we want $|x-3| < 1$. Then, $2 < x < 4$.

So $|x-3| \cdot \displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}+2} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}+2} \cdot |x-3|$

Looks like we want $\delta = \min((\sqrt{3}+2)\epsilon, 1)$

Then $|\sqrt{x+1} - 2| = |x-3| \cdot \displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}+2} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}+2} \cdot |x-3| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}+2} \cdot (\sqrt{3} + 2)\epsilon = \epsilon$

Comment: up vote for providing your attempt, but what is your question? Are you asking if you made a valid proof?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for not clarifying in the post. This is what I came up with, but I have no idea if its correct. I tried using the same idea that one would do in a problem like $\lim_{x \to 2}x^2 = 4$ where you want $|x-2| < 1$.

Comment: Note you can bound the annoying term by $1/2$ (why?).

Comment: Because $\sqrt{x+1} + 2$ will always be greater then $2$ so.......right......did not even realize that.

Comment: Your proof looks exactly right to me. That's the way I would have done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

If $f(x)$ is continuous,

$$\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=f(c)$$

and $\sqrt{x+1}$ is continuous on $[-1,\infty)$

Comment: Assuming that we know $\sqrt{x+1}$ is continuous, though

Comment: While I do see what your saying (which is an excellent observation by the way), my intention was to still use the epsilon delta proof.

Comment: Isn't it obvious that OP is a step behind proving this? Geez...

Comment: The question was a bit vague, and I didn't know that OP was looking for an elipson-delta proof. I just gave the proof I knew; also my reasoning for leaving this answer up

Comment: My bad A.T. . I will remember that for next time I post.

Comment: @PiFarmer86 I think it was a bit of a misunderstanding on both parts

Answer (score 0):

Your derivation is correct (I believe, it looks right but I didn't check every detail), but you are going for too much. To prove the limit statement, you don't need to identify specifically the *largest* $\delta$ that works for each $\epsilon$. You just need to prove there is *some* positive $\delta$ that will work. And you only need to prove it for "small" $\epsilon$ (it automatically follows for larger values). So, assuming $\epsilon < 1$, $\delta = \epsilon$ would work, because the nuisance second term is less than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = y+3$,
so that
$x \to 3$
is the same as
$y \to 0$.

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt{x+1}-2
&=\sqrt{y+4}-2\\
&=(\sqrt{y+4}-2)\dfrac{\sqrt{y+4}+2}{\sqrt{y+4}+2}\\
&=\dfrac{(\sqrt{y+4}-2)(\sqrt{y+4}+2)}{\sqrt{y+4}+2}\\
&=\dfrac{(y+4)-4}{\sqrt{y+4}+2}\\
&=\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{y+4}+2}\\
&\to 0 \text{ as } y \to 0\\
\end{array}
$

Move on - nothing original here.